# Measure of a cone in 4 dimensional space

Tags: geometry, lebesgue-measure

I'm reading a paper titled "Clifford Algebra and Euclid's parameterization of Pythagorean triples" and there is a phrase which I couldn't prove. Here is my question.

In pseudo-quaternions algebra the non-invertible numbers which are null vectors in fact i.e. non-zero vectors of norm zero, form a cone defined by equation $a^2-b^2-c^2+d^2=0$ s.t. $q=a+bi+cj+dk$ is a pseudo quaternion.
So the paper states that this cone has a measure of zero and therefore it will be an almost division algebra.
Can anyone prove this statement? (I mean to prove the measure of the cone is zero.)
Your help will be appreciated.
Btw sorry for my English

Comment: I suspect that most sets defined by an equation $\varphi(x_1,\ldots,x_n)=0$ have measure zero in ${\mathbb R}^n$. In your case, $\varphi$ is differentiable and $\varphi' \not = 0$  except at $x=0$. These properties look sufficient.

Comment: Tahnk you so much sir and it would be greatly appreciated if you could refer some references.

Comment: A reference is the implicit function theorem which implies that if $\varphi\in C^1$ and  $\varphi(x_0) = 0$ and $\nabla\varphi(x_0)\not = 0$, there is a neighborhood of $x_0$ where the set $\{x, \varphi(x) = 0\}$ is the image of a piece of hyperplane by a local $C^1$ diffeomorphism, hence it has measure $0$.